# Make changes to all layout files at once in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I know that we can have different layout files for supporting different screen sizes in Android.

Does anyone know if there is an option to change all other layout files when I make changes to the original layout file? For example, say I have a layout file - main.xml under layout, layout-large, layout-sw600dp and layout-sw720dp directories. If I make some changes to the main.xml in the layout directory, is there any setting which would automatically make that change in the other layout directories as well?

Comment: Depends on what you are about to change. If it is dimensions or colours etc. then you can use values/dimensions.xml and colors.xml etc. and refer to that items. If these are views or view groups that are the same across all resolutions etc, then you could include them in all layouts with an include statement. Any change to the included XML file will then apply to all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Hermann. What do you mean by "include them in all layouts with an include statement" ?Could you please elaborate?

Comment: As Aleksey replied, if you have components such as Views, TextViews or even complete LinearLayouts etc, that are common across all resoutions and orientations, then define them in individual .xml files and use an include statement in the xml files that are customized for resolutions and orientations.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. And i'm not sure there is such tool. Exceptions: naming of params (strings, drawables, etc.).

Some hint: compose layouts from small parts, that inserted using

```
<include />.
```

So when you change small parts – all layout changes (not sure with different sw-*** layouts, but in one folder it works).

Answer (score 0):

For the formatting capabilities I use an answer for this. This refers to the comment above and elaborates on Aleksey's answer.

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/some_id_if_you_nee_one"
        layout="@layout/some_other_xml_file"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

You may add any additional (orientation or resolution specific) formatting like below the `layout=` statment. 
Everything that is not specific to the current resolution/orientation and common for all resolutions/oriantations should go into `some_other_xml_file.xml`

This works for all full views and subclasses of view. If you want something similar only for groups of style attributes then you can start a `styles.xml` and refer to the styles with `style="..."` statements.